# AlertDialog.Builder showing with extra padding for certain length of button options

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

[image]I am using the AlertDialog.Builder like the following.

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setMessage("test")
                .setNegativeButton("Talk Abalone", dialogClickListener)
                .setNeutralButton("Love the Abalone", dialogClickListener).show();
```

There is some extra padding at the bottom when the length of the text is at "Keep the Abalone" and "Edit Abalone" combined. If I remove a word, then the padding at the bottom no longer exist and everything works fine. If the language is in other language, making the length of the string shorter or longer, there is no extra padding for shorter string or the two options just stack together. Is this a bug in AlertDialog.Builder? Any idea on how to fix it? Thank you[image]

Comment: is there a reason for using .setNeutralButton() instead of .setPositiveButton()?

Comment: @Xiaofan Wu See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27482658/5978440)

Comment: you can design your own custom layout and use it.

Comment: @nik, I can use setPositiveButton, same thing

Comment: @Sniffer So I just force the button to align right and stack together?

Comment: You can try it but also check it on TAB device also

Comment: Its working fine at my end. @XiaofanWu

Comment: @Ankita I think it also depends on the device, this works for smaller or bigger devices.